# Setting an UIImage for UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: ios, uibutton

[image: The images]

board[i] is an array of UIButtons that I have created programmmatically, and I can't change their image for UIControlStateHighlighted:

```
    [board[i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"block"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [board[i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blockPressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

When I press the button with the mouse in the simulator the image doesn't change. I think this is a very noob question, but I don't what the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when adding button programatically do this:

1. add target of each same.
2. provide tag all button from 0 to count.
3. set UserInteraction to true
4. setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blockPressed.png"]  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted if u want button to be highlited

Now button is pressed same method is called for all button: For example

```
-(void)ButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *btntouched = sender;
   NSLog(@"%@", btntouched);
   [btntouched setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blockPressed.png"]  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];// it can be forState:UIControlStateNormal also
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't change the higlighted image.
<code>board[i] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [board[i] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [board[i] addTarget:self    action:@selector(ButtonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
</code><code>
-(void)ButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btntouched = sender;
    NSLog(@"%@", btntouched);
    [btntouched setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blockPressed.png"]  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}</code>

Comment: change forState:UIControlStateNormal in ButtonTouched event

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are triggering the highlighted state. This could be because they are not set to have interaction enabled. Or there is something else missing from the way you set up your buttons.

The other thing you can try is to add a selector to each of the buttons for when they are touched, and then change the image by referencing sender for the selector function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've made sure your image doesn't return `nil`, this code should work:

```
[myUIButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myHighlightedButtonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

It should work find if you call that line in your `viewDidLoad()`.